# Azure WebApp Deployment makes the application slow to load after deployement

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have to run coded UI test on the application after the deployment of the changes made but the coded ui test fails as the application takes too much time to load.Azure WebApp Deployment makes the application slow to load after deployment.What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Scale up? Increase timeout?

Comment: timeout of that particular webapp deployment task is zero